# Get drop position of item in cdkDropList

Tags: angular, drag-and-drop, angular-material, angular-cdk

I'm trying to get (or calculate) the x/y coordinates of a dropped item in an angular-material cdkDropList. I've studied the documentation https://material.angular.io/cdk/drag-drop/api#CdkDragDrop and found there should be a property called "distance" in the CdkDragDrop interface but I can't find it in the console log of the event:

```
drop(event: CdkDragDrop<string[]>) {
    console.log(event);
}
```

I've only found container, currentIndex, item, previousContainer, previousIndex.
By the way: I'm new to angular and this and the documentation confuses me :(

thx and greetings

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, forget it... the property distance was introduced in version 8.0.1 and I'm on 7.1.0...

**Update**

To get the position in this version you can use the cdkDragMoved event like shown here:

https://grokonez.com/frontend/angular/angular-7/angular-7-drag-and-drop-example-angular-material-cdk

html Part:

```
<div cdkDrag class="drag-box"
  (cdkDragStarted)="dragStarted($event)"
  (cdkDragEnded)="dragEnded($event)"
  (cdkDragMoved)="dragMoved($event)"
>
  drag me
</div>
<p>{{state}} {{position}}</p>
```

and in TypeScript:

```
import { CdkDragEnd, CdkDragStart, CdkDragMove } from '@angular/cdk/drag-drop';
...
export class DragComponent implements OnInit {
  state = '';
  position = '';
  ...

  dragStarted(event: CdkDragStart) {
    this.state = 'dragStarted';
  }

  dragEnded(event: CdkDragEnd) {
    this.state = 'dragEnded';
  }

  dragMoved(event: CdkDragMove) {
    this.position = `> Position X: ${event.pointerPosition.x} - Y: ${event.pointerPosition.y}`;
  }
}
```